# Unable to update jhipster version

Tags: jhipster

Currently I am using Jhipster 2.23.0 version but 2.23.1 is available so tried to update Jhipster using `npm update -g generator-jhipster` but still when i do yo `jhipster` it shows 2.23.0 version.

Comment: Did you try just using `yo`? It will ask you which generator you want to update

Comment: i tried doing `yo` it gives `jhipster` in its generator list but when i try  to update is it gives error for permission of administrator ,i also tried going `sudo yo` but it is giving same error.

Comment: And did you try with the correct permissions? If you have installed it globally and you are not the administrator, that's normal you can't upgrade

Comment: Then how to upgrade,should I install it again

Comment: You need to have the right permissions on your system  JHipster can't go past your OS permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also recently update my JHipster application. To be sure that your generator is updated check first if the version you want, got installed properly:

npm list  generator-jhipster

After that yo jhipster will update your application.
As a hint allways read the releas notes:
http://jhipster.github.io/releases/

it can save you a lot of time.

cheers,
duderoot

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command

npm update -g generator-jhipster@2.23.1

Comment: please try  removing the exiting package by

npm update -g generator-jhipster  and then try to install again .

Comment: I have uninstalled and installed it again.That how i updated ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest 2.26.2 now and with no issues. When yo changes, you will be notified to update. I just did:

npm install -g yo

and then ...

npm install -g generator-jhipster

JHipster is a Yeoman generator so I assume that yo needed update first. Has your issue been remedied?

Comment: Yes..uninstalled existing jhipster and installed it again